# updating a field on update of other field in same row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a Table like this:

**user_level**

```
uid | level_order | current_level
---------------------------------
1   | 1,2,3       | 1
2   | 4,5,6       | 4
3   | 7,8,9       | 7
```

now, if I update level_order field for a particular user, i want to update current_level using trigger or procedure.

For Example if I run this query :
`update user_level set level_order = '21,22,23' where uid=1;`
then  table should update like this:

```
    uid | level_order | current_level
    ---------------------------------
    1   | 21,22,23    | 21
    2   | 4,5,6       | 4
    3   | 7,8,9       | 7
```

Is it possible using `trigger` or `procedure`.
I am using `MYSQL`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need trigger.You can update it directly like this.

```
   update user_level 
           set level_order = '21,22,23', 
           current_level=SUBSTRING_INDEX('21,22,23', ',', 1) 
           where uid=1;
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2340b/1)

Comment: this is helpful but this value `21,22,23` is coming dynamically, so i have to fetch updated `level_order` also.

Comment: @HarjeetJadeja the way you pass the value to level order the same you pass the value to current level.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
create trigger AutoUpdateCurrentLevelFromUserLevel
after update
on UserLevel
for each row
set CurrentLevel="{your value here}"
```

Comment: i have tried this one but the issue id it will set all values `21,22,23` to `current_level`.
I want to set only first value that is `21`. And this values are dynamic.

Comment: not very sure,but try this
set CurrentLevel=SUBSTRING_INDEX(level_order, ',', 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger to achieve the same. Trigger are very useful in scenario like the one you mentioned above for implementing constraints. Use a update trigger for the same. Also you can embed the update to the new row in your query itself.